# Javascript - Submit Text Field, Show Div, Hide All Others

Tags: javascript

I have a simple form (text field and submit button). I am trying to have the user submit a number, and the resulting number will display one div (from a set of divs).

I tried using [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/LfzYc/) as a base (when the user clicks a link, it shows a div, but hides others).

My test is below:

```
var divState = {};

function showhide(oFrm) {
    var dividnum = oFrm.Inputed.value;
    var prepar = "para";
    var divid = prepar + theInput; /* should result in something like "para52" */


    divState[divid] = (divState[divid]) ? false : true; 
    //close others
    for (var div in divState){
        if (divState[div] && div != divid){
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
            divState[div] = false;
        }
    }

    divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LfzYc/431/

Note: I am NOT proficient in JavaScript at all, which is why I am having difficulty.

Also, I'd like to add a function ... if the number entered is not between 1-4, show a different div, maybe with the id `paraEnd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfzYc/437/) based on your one. I hope I've done what you want. I changed the `showhide` function and your HTML (fixed `div`'s IDs and added one more `div#paraEnd`). I'd suggest you refactoring your code.

Comment: It looks great. How can the code be modified to allow for alot more paragraphs?  I have 142 entries ... (not just 4). I'm assuming line 7 has to be revised... ['1', '2', '3', '4'].

Comment: I tried changing the if statement to be:  if (dividnum >= 142) {  ... but it didn't work

Comment: @user3412194 Please look at [the following jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfzYc/438/) I updated the code.

Comment: @user3412194 I refactored the code a bit. You can look at [this one jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfzYc/439/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery to have an easy way to manipulate the DOM.
Using jQuery I made an example for you, just change your JS and paste mine:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function ($) {

        // get the paragraphs
        var paragraphs = $('.paragraph');

        // form submit
        $('#paragraphform').submit(function (e) {
            // prevent the event to flow
            e.preventDefault();

            // get the input value
            var value = $('#Inputed').val() - 1;

            // reset all divs removing active css class
            paragraphs.removeClass('active');
            $('.error').removeClass('active');

            // verify if the value doens't exist
            if(value < 0 || value > paragraphs.length - 1) {
                $('.error').addClass('active');
                return;
            }

            // show the active div
            paragraphs.eq(value).addClass('active');
        }); 

    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Is that what you need?

If you not familiar with jQuery, this is the jquery Learn Center:
https://learn.jquery.com/

And this is a nice tutorial for beginners:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/